# parse .json files in mapreduce

Tags: java, json, hadoop

I am new to json on hadoop, I have huge log files which are of type .json. I need to parse these logs in mapreduce. I need example of mapreduce jobs which takes input of .json file parses it and outputs it to either a text file or .json file.

```
[  
    {  
        "name":"John",
        "city":"Berlin",
        "cars":[  
            "audi",
            "bmw"
        ],
        "job":"Teacher"
    },
    {  
        "name":"Mark",
        "city":"Oslo",
        "cars":[  
            "VW",
            "Toyata"
        ],
        "job":"Doctor"
    }
]
```

for example the above json should be parsed in mapreduce to give me output which has key:name and in values all the names appended

Answer (score 0):

Google GSON's JsonReader might be what you need.  Not exactly sure what you're trying to do with the json data but you should be able to stream in the JSON from a file with JsonReader and handle it accordingly

https://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/stream/JsonReader.html

Comment: I have a very big log json file like the above , I need to process this on hadoop mapreduce, the input format of the file for hadoop mapreduce should be json, and I dont know how to take that, the parsing should be done in such a way that the key should take name and values should have all the names that appear in all the jason record. Like for the above example my reducer should give me output as name:John, Mark

Answer (score 0):

To read any data into your program you need an implementation of *InputFormat* 
Be it a JSON XML or Avro reader the implementation should over ride the below method

public abstract

```
 RecordReader<K,V> createRecordReader(InputSplit split,
                                         TaskAttemptContext context
                                        ) throws IOException, 
                                                 InterruptedException;
```

If you are looking for an existing implementation just google or see here [custom inputformat for reading json in hadoop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18593595/custom-inputformat-for-reading-json-in-hadoop)

You can refer this source for implementation details http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.kitesdk/kite-data-core/0.18.0/org/kitesdk/data/spi/filesystem/JSONInputFormat.java

The output format is independent of this.You can choose input and output types to your reducer as you need.Only that if you want to produce JSON files you will need a JSONOutputFormat (an implementation of FileOutputFormat)